# How to get the variable which is used twice

Tags: tensorflow2.0

My question is about tf.function-decorated function which complains about that variable is used twice ?

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

How can i debug this in colab/jupyter notebook to get the name of this variable?

Comment: Any luck with it? Running within a .py file showed me the exact line number where the ValueError occurred, which was indeed a tf.Variable as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look [this section](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/#from-eager-to-tffunction-the-need-to-refactor) of this [article](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/) - it contains the description of the problem you're facing right now.

In short, you're defining inside a function a `tf.Variable` (one or more). Even though you call this function only once, `tf.function` executes the function more than 1 time to convert it to its graph representation, making `tf.function` raise the exception you're getting.

You have to refactor your code in order to declare any variable outside the function body. At the time of writing, there is no way to know which variable caused the error (since ever `tf.Variable` declared in the object would make tf.function to raise the same error)

Comment: i know https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/function , but in my generator() function i declare no tf.variable, so i dont know where this error comes from

Comment: There is something that's declaring it for you. A Keras layer, an operation that accumulates values, ...

Comment: that seemed so, thats why i want to know if the debug output could be more verbose or any other hint howto debug this?  The code that complains about it, should know the name of the va?riable it complains about, so why does it not print it?

Comment: Perhaps it's better opening an issue on Github